# StrongLoop Mongodb Models

Tags: mongodb, strongloop, loopback

I'm attempting to create a very simple loopback application that connects to a Mongo database.

To get started, I have created a mongo database using data from the mongo [website](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/import-data/) that uses this [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json) of restaurants.

How can I model this structure in a loopback application?  All I can find is simple examples that do not contain nested structures.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need following models:

#### Restaurant

- id (Type: Object, Autogenerated)
- name (Type: String)
- borough (Type: String)
- cuisine (Type: String)
- address (hasOne relation with an addressId field pointing to one address document (row) in collection (table))
- grades (hasMany relation)

#### RestaurantGrade

- id (Type: Object, Autogenerated)
- grade (Type: String)
- score (Type: Number)
- date (Type: Date)
- restaurantId (belongsTo relation)

#### Address

- id (Type: Object, Autogenerated)
- building (Type: String)
- street (Type: String)
- zipCode (Type: String)
- coord (Type: GeoPoint)

The normalization process of tables of relational database still applies when creating MongoDB collections. Check the following with your use cases before considering nested structure.

Do yo need to show the nested (embedded) data structure as static representation of data or you want to user sort, search and limit on the fields of embedded objects?

For example, if you want to see all restaurants for a zipcode, then you should not embed address in the **Restaurant** collection but instead separate it out in a different collection (as in above models).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll give it a go.  Are there any examples of this that you know of?  Having a working reference would be very useful as I'm learning the platform.

Comment: Please check if you have gone through these [tutorials](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Tutorials-and-examples.html). By going through these examples, you should be able to get started.

Comment: I think I understand the modelling concept. What I'm missing and cannot seem to find in the examples, is how a model relates to either a document with nested objects, or a separate collection.

Comment: Got it.  They key to this is 'Embedded models and relations'.  I can now expose the sample data collection.